# Git - using branches for environment configurations

Tags: git, branch

I have a situation at work where I need to provide some version control to various product configuration files, mostly xml.  I also need to have some form of access control for certain environment configurations(staging, production).

We can have up to 13 different environments for many of our applications from development to production.

What I was thinking of doing was to use git as the vcs, and create a branch for each environment. The dev branch would be deployed to the dev environment, etc etc. I'd also lock down the master branch so that only certain people can merge the 'release' or 'prod' branches that get deployed to prod.

Has anyone used git for a situation like this? I've tested it out and I can make it work, but I'm not sure if it's just a really bad idea and maybe I should work on another solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://gitlab.com, you can setup an account for free and have unlimited private repos. You can also group repos into projects.

It seems like in this situation it would be better to have a project with several repos in the project. Each repo could then have a master branch, dev branch, and say a new features branch.

This way you can also add members to the project and give certain permissions to members as well.

Comment: Yea we have our own private git server. I have a group created and each application has its own repo in the group. And each repo has up to 13 branches, one for each environment.  I'm more concerned with is this is actually a good idea/way to use git. I have the technicalities figured out.

Comment: Then would it make sense to group into a project with multiple repos ? Just a suggestion, could get messy with multiple branches for different configs.

Comment: I thought about that too. I'd rather have one group that is managed by our support staff for these products instead of having separate groups for every app(hundreds). But maybe that will be the easiest way to go.

Comment: In gitlab you can create a group and then have hundreds of repos (apps) inside of that group. Then you just give support access to that group. Not sure what features your private git setup supports.

Comment: What I might end up doing is instead of having a branch for each env, I'll have a folder for each env in the project. During the deploy, I'll just grab the appropriate files from the env folder. I'll still use a release/prod branch for production deployments and merge requests.

Comment: Seems like a valid solution!